# How to make text shift left to reveal what you're typing in input html

Tags: html, css, input, text, scroll

When I am typing in an input, the text is not shown after the field is filled only by scrolling. I need to make it scroll automatically when adding a value on it.

[image]

I try the overflow to visible or hidden or auto but nothing works

[image]

Comment: can you put your input text-align:right ?

Comment: yes i put that before

Comment: so? it's working, Input is beginning at right, when the input is filled text continue left. Perhaps I didn't understand the question!

Comment: as in the picture the input field is full it will not automatic move left

Comment: Can you create a minimal reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `justify-content:flex-start;`  on the display container, you should try `justify-content:flex-end;` instead.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: no i am using the flex-end